# Android : Añadir Imágenes en Adapter

Tags: android-studio

estoy realizando un lector rss, pero no sé como añadir imágenes, podéis ayudarme?

Ahora mismo he conseguido añadir de cada noticia:
Titulo,
Descripción
Enlace

me faltaría imagen.. os pongo parte del código:

La clase adaptador:

```
ADAPTADOR:

package eac2.eac2_maqueda_m.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import eac2.eac2_maqueda_m.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import eac2.eac2_maqueda_m.Model.RssObject;
import eac2.eac2_maqueda_m.R;

/**
* Created by Montse on 23/10/2017.
*/

class FeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener,View.OnLongClickListener{

public TextView txtTitle, txtPubDate, txtContent;
    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public FeedViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        txtTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        txtPubDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPubDate);
        txtContent = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);

        //Eventos

        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);

    }

    public void setItemClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition(),false);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(view,getAdapterPosition(),true);
        return true;
    }
}

public class FeedAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FeedViewHolder> {

    private RssObject rssObject;
    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public FeedAdapter(RssObject rssObject, Context mContext) {
        this.rssObject = rssObject;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    }

    @Override
    public FeedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
      View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row,parent,false);
        return new FeedViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FeedViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtTitle.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txtPubDate.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getPubDate());
        holder.txtContent.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getContent());



        // al fer click alguna noticia...
        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                if(!isLongClick){
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink()));
                    mContext.startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return rssObject.items.size();
    }
}
```

CLASSE FEED

```
public class Feed
{
    public String url;
    public String title ;
    public String link ;
    public String author ;
    public String description ;
    public String image ;

    public Feed(String url, String title, String link, String author, String description, String image) {
        this.url = url;
        this.title = title;
        this.link = link;
        this.author = author;
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

LA CLASSE ITEM

```
    package eac2.eac2_maqueda_m.Model;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Montse on 23/10/2017.
 */

public class Item {

    public String title;
    public String pubDate;
    public String link;
    public String guid;
    public String author;
    public String thumbnail ;
    public String description ;
    public String content ;
    public Enclosure enclosure ;
    public List<Object> categories;


    public Item(String title, String pubDate, String link, String guid, String author, String thumbnail, String description, String content, Enclosure enclosure, List<Object> categories) {
        this.title = title;
        this.pubDate = pubDate;
        this.link = link;
        this.guid = guid;
        this.author = author;
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
        this.description = description;
        this.content = content;
        this.enclosure = enclosure;
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getPubDate() {
        return pubDate;
    }

    public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
        this.pubDate = pubDate;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getGuid() {
        return guid;
    }

    public void setGuid(String guid) {
        this.guid = guid;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getThumbnail() {
        return thumbnail;
    }

    public void setThumbnail(String thumbnail) {
        this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Enclosure getEnclosure() {
        return enclosure;
    }

    public void setEnclosure(Enclosure enclosure) {
        this.enclosure = enclosure;
    }

    public List<Object> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<Object> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }
}
```

CLASSE RSS OBJETO

```
   package eac2.eac2_maqueda_m.Model;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Montse on 17/10/2017.
 * Tota la info de com he tret aquestes dades a Item.java
 */

    public class RssObject
    {
        public String status ;
        public Feed feed;
        public List<Item> items;


    public RssObject(String status, Feed feed, List<Item> items) {
        this.status = status;
        this.feed = feed;
        this.items = items;

    }

        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }

        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }

        public Feed getFeed() {
            return feed;
        }

        public void setFeed(Feed feed) {
            this.feed = feed;
        }

        public List<Item> getItems() {
            return items;
        }

        public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
            this.items = items;
        }
    }
```

gracias a todos estoy algo pez..:(

ADJUNTO LAYOUT ROW

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="367dp"
        android:layout_height="191dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtPubDate"
            android:layout_width="184dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2017-10-23 18:08:00"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="88dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtContent"
            android:layout_width="182dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Contingut"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
            android:layout_width="183dp"
            android:layout_height="62dp"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtContent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtPubDate"
            android:text="Titol"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgImagen"
            android:layout_width="163dp"
            android:layout_height="167dp"
            android:contentDescription="" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: A que te refieres con "algo pez"? hehe, simplemente agrega otro elemento en tu layout, un ImageView, obtén la referencia y carga la imagen en este.

Comment: @Jorgesys jajajaj algo pez es como decir algo aplatadana.. no sé.. xD jajaja como te lo explico.. algo verde? Que me cuesta ? XD :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega dentro de tu layout `row.xml` un `ImageView` que es el que contendrá la imagen, obtén su referencia:

```
   public TextView txtTitle, txtPubDate, txtContent;
    public ImageView imgImagen;

        public FeedViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            txtTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
            txtPubDate = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtPubDate);
            txtContent = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtContent);

            imgImagen= (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgImagen);

            ...
            ...
```

y dentro de tu Adapter en el método `onBindViewHolder()` puedes agregar la imagen, para esto te recomiendo usar [Picasso](https://geekytheory.com/gestion-de-imagenes-en-android-con-picasso), donde defines la url que contiene la imagen.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FeedViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtTitle.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getTitle());
        holder.txtPubDate.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getPubDate());
        holder.txtContent.setText(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getContent());

//* Carga Imagen.
Picasso.with(mContext).load(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getThumbnail()).into(holder.imgImagen);


        // al fer click alguna noticia...
        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                if(!isLongClick){
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(rssObject.getItems().get(position).getLink()));
                    mContext.startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: ahora en un rato lo pruebo y te comento!! gracias _***********

Comment: hay algo que hago mal con la imagen: <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgImagen"
            android:layout_width="163dp"
            android:layout_height="167dp"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image"
            android:contentDescription="" />

Comment: no acaba de mostrarse.. T_T

Comment: También me da error el getUrl.. he puesto getLink..

Comment: primeramente realiza el ejemplo sin obtener la imagen de la url ya que puede no exista, elimina la linea de picasso y primero revisa se cargue la imagen ic_menu_report_image . Que error muestra? Agrega tu layout en la pregunta.

Comment: no me muestra error cuando lo elimino.. no sé.. que hago mal..T_T he adjuntado el layout row.

Comment: la idea es que la imagen salga a la izquierda y la info a la derecha.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67550/discussion-on-answer-by-jorgesys-android-anadir-imagenes-en-adapter).